# n-ary version of gcd$(a,b)\space $lcm$(a,b)$ = $ab$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

This question was motivated by pondering [this lcm identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/is-there-a-direct-proof-of-this-lcm-identity).

Consider that $\gcd(1,6,15) = 1$, but $\operatorname{lcm}(1,6,15)=30$, but $1\cdot 6\cdot 15 = 90$.  $(2,6,15)$ shows a similar phenomenon.

So what is the correct identity for $n$-ary $\gcd$/$\operatorname{lcm}$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For $n \ge 2$ there isn't just one identity; there are actually $n+1$ identities, half of which are dual to the other half, and two of which are the trivial identity $a_1 ... a_n = a_1 ... a_n$.  The first two are as follows.  Let $P = a_1 ... a_n$.  Then

$\displaystyle a_1 ... a_n = \text{gcd}(a_1, a_2, ... a_n) \text{lcm} \left( \frac{P}{a_1}, \frac{P}{a_2}, ... \right).$

$\displaystyle a_1 ... a_n = \text{gcd}(a_1 a_2, a_1 a_3, ..., a_{n-1} a_n) \text{lcm} \left( \frac{P}{a_1 a_2}, \frac{P}{a_1 a_3}, ..., \frac{P}{a_{n-1} a_n} \right).$

The other identities are similar.  This is because "pointwise" (e.g. at a particular prime $p$) the two-variable identity is just the identity $\text{min}(a, b) + \text{max}(a, b) = a + b$ for non-negative integers $a, b$, and the above identities are the natural generalization of this one.

Comment: Right, so there is an inclusion-exclusion argument lurking in the background.  And I believe the above can be stated as a single identity (just multiply them all together!) whilst retaining its 'character'.

Comment: I don't see any inclusion-exclusion argument in the background. Isn't this just splitting $x_1 + \dots + x_n$ as (smallest sum of k terms) + (largest sum of n-k terms)?

Answer (score 9):

Such generalizations of gcd & lcm identities occur frequently as problems. Below are a couple of examples - which include references to prior literature, e.g. to an inclusion-exclusion max/min proof in Polya & Szego's problem book. They're problem E2229 from the Monthly 77 1970 p. 402; problem 1344 from Math. Mag. 64 1990 p. 134.

[image]

[image]

[image]