# this came in my exam and i could not answer it . any help is appreciated.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

The LCM of165, 176, 385 and 495 is k. When is divided by the HCF of the numbers, the quotientis p. What is the value of p?

A 2520

B 5040

C 6720

D 3360

i have familiar with basic concepts of lcm and hcf but these numbers seem terrifying to me.

Comment: Hint;  work with the prime factorings of each number.

Comment: Do you know how to find lcm of those numbers?

Comment: i could break them into factors and then find their lcm but i would take time and in exam time and pressure it isnt easy. there is a formula used in my exam syllabus that product of two numbers=product of their lcm and hcf. i think we have to use this somehow .

Comment: There are similar related formulas for more than two terms... [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/n-ary-version-of-gcda-b-space-lcma-b-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1).  I don't see it immediately being useful however for your problem.  You would have $165\cdot 176\cdot 385\cdot 495 = \gcd(176\cdot 385\cdot 495, 165\cdot 385\cdot 495, 165\cdot 176\cdot 495, 165\cdot 176\cdot 385)\cdot \text{lcm}(165, 176, 385, 495)$ or similar.

Comment: Personally, I find it much easier to recognize these as all being multiples of $11$, explicitly with the second as being $2^4\times 11$ and the others being odd multiples of $11$, so it is quick to see that the $\gcd$ is $11$ itself.  So, dividing each number by $11$ the question is effectively asking for $\text{lcm}(15,16,35,45)$ which should be relatively painless.

Comment: Hint: the (obvious) power of $2$ in the LCM/GCD  excludes all but one choice - see my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spot by inspection or divisibility tests that each number is a multiple of $11$ and the second number is $16\times 11 = 2^4\times 11$ while the other numbers are all odd multiples of $11$.

It follows that the $\gcd$ of the numbers is then $11$.

Recognize that $\text{lcm}(a,b,c,d)/\gcd(a,b,c,d) = \text{lcm}(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b,c,d)},\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b,c,d)},\dots,\frac{d}{\gcd(a,b,c,d)})$ so the problem simplifies as $\text{lcm}(15,16,35,45) = \text{lcm}(3\cdot 5, 2^4,5\cdot 7, 3^2\cdot 5)$

We can then see that the result will be $2^4\times 3^2\times 5\times 7 = 5040$

Comment: Much simpler to examine only the prime $2$, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy mental way: clearly the power of $\,2\,$ in ${\small \rm\color{#0a0}{LCM}/\color{#c00}{GCD}} = \color{#0a0}4\!-\!\color{#c00}0,\,$ but $\,2^{\large 4}\!\nmid 2520,\,$ $2^{\large 5}\!\mid 3360\mid 6720 $

Comment: That's a good standard test taking strategy, to eliminate possibilities, but if there was a "none of the above" option, it doesn't help you decide between them.  Depending on the available options, finishing the problem may be a better approach than eliminating the bad answers.

Comment: @JMoravitz But there is no "none of the above" here (and we could continue this way if we needed to). It is highly likely that the problem was *designed* to be quickly solvable as above.