# LCM of binomial coefficients and related functions

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, arithmetic-functions, least-common-multiple

I know about the following identity: $$\displaystyle \text{lcm} \left( {n \choose 0}, {n \choose 1}, ... {n \choose n} \right) = \frac{\text{lcm}(1, 2, ... n+1)}{n+1}$$
1) Is there any method to find $$\displaystyle \text{lcm} \left( {n \choose 0}, {n \choose 1}, ... {n \choose k} \right)$$ for any $k \le n$ without evaluating all the binomial coefficients?

2)Let me define $$g(n,k)=\displaystyle \text k{n \choose k}$$
$$\displaystyle \text{lcm} \left( g(n,0), g(n,1), ... g(n,n) \right)=\text{lcm}(1, 2, ... n)$$
Can we find $$\displaystyle \text{lcm} \left( g(n,0), g(n,1), ... g(n,k) \right)$$ for any $k \le n$ ?

EDIT:
$$\displaystyle \text{lcm} \left( {n \choose 0}, {n \choose 1}, ... {n \choose k} \right)=\frac{\text{lcm}(n-k+1,n-k+2, ... n+1)}{n+1}$$
$$\displaystyle \text{lcm} \left( g(n,0), g(n,1), ... g(n,k) \right)=\text{lcm}(n-k,n-k+1, ... n)$$

Comment: For 1)Refer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/is-there-a-direct-proof-of-this-lcm-identity?rq=1

Comment: @JuanJellyfish , thanks for the reference. But what about $g(n,k)$?