# Determine LCM of C(n,1) , C(n,2) , C(n,3) ....... C(n,k)

Tags: combinations, prime-factorization

Is there a smart precise way to determine LCM of  $C(n,1) , C(n,2) , C(n,3) ,\ldots, C(n,k)$ :

Here $C(n,k)$ denotes no. of combinations of n objects taken k at a time.

Comment: so $C\left(n,k\right)={n \choose k}$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is highly likely to be from an ongoing competition.

Answer (score 3):

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002944) says that $\operatorname{lcm}(C(n,1) , C(n,2) , C(n,3) ,\ldots, C(n,n)) = \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n+1)/(n+1)$. This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/is-there-a-direct-proof-of-this-lcm-identity) contains a proof. However, no simpler expression is known for $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)$.

It seems unlikely that there is a simple expression for the general case
$\operatorname{lcm}(C(n,1) , C(n,2) , C(n,3) ,\ldots, C(n,k))$.

Comment: can we get forula for for   1.C(n,1)+2.C(n,2)....k.C(n,k) ?

Comment: @user2970016, I think it's unlikely, but ask a separate question.