# Proving that a prime factor greater than $n$ divides ${{x+n} \choose {n}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, factorial

I have been thinking about the [Sylvester and Schur theorem](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1934-01.pdf) and wondering if there is an alternative argument.

Let $v_p(n)$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$.

It occurs to me that:

> $$v_p\left({{x+n}\choose{n}}\right) \le \max\left(v_p(x+1), v_p(x+2), \dots, v_p(x+n)\right)$$

Note: I have detailed my reasoning [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2778734/48606).

If this assumption is correct, would the following be a valid argument for establishing that if $n \ge 8, x \ge \frac{n}{2}$, then a prime $p > n$ divides ${{x+n}\choose{n}}$:

(1)  Let $T$ be the set $\{x + 1, x + 2, \dots, x+n\}$ so that:

> $${{x+n}\choose{n}} = \frac{\prod\limits_{t \in T}t}{n!}$$

(2)  Assume that no primes greater than $n$ divide ${{x+n}\choose{n}}$.

(3)  Let $U = \prod\limits_{p \le n}p^{v_p\left({{x+n}\choose{n}}\right)}$ so that:

> $${{x+n}\choose{n}} = U$$

(4)  If my assumption is correct, there exists a set $S$ such that $S \subset T$ and $|S| = \pi(n)$ and there exists $U'$ such that  $\prod\limits_{s \in S}s = UU'$, and $V = \dfrac{\prod\limits_{t \in T}t}{\prod\limits_{s \in S}s}$ so that:

> $${{x+n}\choose{n}} = U = \frac{UU'V}{n!}$$

(5)  As $x$ increases and $n$ stays the same, if there are no primes greater than $n$, then $U$ will change but $U'V$ will stay constant. But this is clearly impossible since $V$ does not stay constant and $U' \ge 1$.

(6)  Let $w = n - \pi(n)$.  At all times, the values of $V$ is constrained by:

$$\frac{(x+w)!}{x!} \le V \le \frac{(x+n)!}{(x+n-w)!}$$

(7)  At $x = 0$, for example:

> $$w! \le V \le \frac{n!}{(n-w)!}$$

(7) As $x$ increases, this inequality changes, and eventually the minimum bound of the higher $x$ is greater than the maximum bound of the lower $x$.  At this point, the minimum value of $V$ has increased independently of $U$ and it follows that:

> $${{x+n}\choose{n}} > U$$.

(8)  The first point where this definitely occurs for $n\ge 8$ is when $x > \frac{n}{2}$:

> It is well known for $n\ge 8$, $\pi(n) \le \frac{n}{2}$ so that:
>
> $\frac{n}{2} + w > \pi(n) + w = \pi(n) + n - \pi(n) = n$

Comment: In (5), "But this is clearly impossible since $V$ does not stay constant and $U' \ge 1$" Yes, $V$ does not stay constant, but I don't get where $U'\ge 1$ comes from when you just defined $U'$ as $\prod\limits_{s \in S}s/U$.